# Cassandra client code with high read throughput with row_cache optimization

Tags: caching, memory, cassandra, client

Can someone point me to cassandra client code that can achieve a read throughput of at least hundreds of thousands of reads/s if I keep reading the same record (or even a small number of records) over and over? I believe `row_cache_size_in_mb` is supposed to cache frequently used records in memory, but setting it to say 10MB seems to make no difference.

I tried `cassandra-stress` of course, but the highest read throughput it achieves with 1KB records `(-col size=UNIFORM\(1000..1000\))` is ~15K/s.

With low numbers like above, I can easily write an in-memory hashmap based cache that will give me at least a million reads per second for a small working set size. How do I make cassandra do this automatically for me? Or is it not supposed to achieve performance close to an in-memory map even for a tiny working set size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my findings: when I enable row_cache, counter_cache, and key_cache all to sizable values, I am able to verify using "top" that cassandra does no disk I/O at all; all three seem necessary to ensure no disk activity. Yet, despite zero disk I/O, the throughput is <20K/s even for reading a single record over and over. This likely confirms (as also alluded to in my comment) that cassandra incurs the cost of serialization and deserialization even if its operations are completely in-memory, i.e., it is not designed to compete with native hashmap performance. So, if you want get native hashmap speeds for a small-working-set workload but expand to disk if the map grows big, you would need to write your own cache on top of cassandra (or any of the other key-value stores like mongo, redis, etc. for that matter).

For those interested, I also verified that redis is the fastest among cassandra, mongo, and redis for a simple get/put small-working-set workload, but even redis gets at best ~35K/s read throughput (largely independent, by design, of the request size), which hardly comes anywhere close to native hashmap performance that simply returns pointers and can do so comfortably at over 2 million/s.

Comment: Thank you for the update. As you said, it's pretty obvious that having a schema full database like Cassandra, performance in memory is slower than a native HashMap. The reason is not only because of ser/deser but also because Cassandra creates extra objects to encapsulate the results into columns/rows. This remark applies to other NoSQL solutions too

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone point me to cassandra client code that can achieve a read throughput of at least hundreds of thousands of reads/s if I keep reading the same record (or even a small number of records) over and over?

There are some solution for this scenario

One idea is to use row cache but be careful, any update/delete to a single column will invalidate the whole partition from the cache so you loose all the benefit. Row cache best usage is for small dataset and are frequently read but almost never modified.

Are you sure that your cassandra-stress scenario never update or write to the same partition over and over again ?

Comment: The stress tool does only writes in a separate first stage and then does only reads in the next stage. The two stages are separate processes run sequentially.

Comment: Here's how I basically run them: tools/bin/cassandra-stress -n write 10000; tools/bin/cassandra-stress -n read 10000. I also sometimes use other options to benchmark different request sizes, etc. I tried row cache sizes of 10 and 100MB but it didn't help.

Comment: My feeling is that the read of 10 000 records are done only once by the cassandra-stress tool so you don't benefit too much (not to say at all) from the cache. Indeed, when accessing a row for a first time it is loaded into the cache from disk but if you don't read the same row after that, it's pretty useless. I would suggest to start by writing 10 000 rows, then executing cassandrea-stress with reading 10 000 rows multiple times (10 times) to benefit from the caching and put a large cache size (100Mb) for ex. Which version of Cassandra are you using ?

Comment: I did do that anyway. I usually run it a few times (in addition to it itself running it many times with different thread counts all the way from 4 to nearly 1000 threads). I also tried 100Mb but there was no change. I am using 3.5.

Comment: I am guessing that cassandra is serializing and deserializing over a TCP connection, so that's what limits its throughput to <20K/s on my machine. With serialization, you can never get a million reads/s like a native hashmap as that is just returning pointers. Does this explanation seem right or is there a way to get cassandra to do even 100K reads/s for the same record over and over?

Comment: thanks for your comments. If you are interested, I posted my findings below.